# How to fix: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel, datatables

I'm new with Laravel and I wanted to get started with Bootstrap Modal.
I'm using library DataTables and I build the Update function around it but I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined
    at Ha (jquery.dataTables.min.js:24)
    at O (jquery.dataTables.min.js:16)
    at HTMLTableRowElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:17)
    at app.js:1
    at Function.map (app.js:1)
    at E.fn.init.map (app.js:1)
    at na (jquery.dataTables.min.js:16)
    at e (jquery.dataTables.min.js:92)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:93)
    at Function.each (app.js:1)
```

Here is my table code:

```
<div class="container">
  <table id="tabladedatos" class="table">
<thead class="thead-dark">
<tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>First name</th>
  <th>Last name</th>
  <th>Address</th>
  <th>Mobile</th>
  <th>Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  @foreach($emps as $emp)
    <tr>
      <td> {{$emp->id}} </td>
      <td> {{$emp->fname}} </td>
      <td> {{$emp->lname}} </td>
      <td> {{$emp->address}} </td>
      <td> {{$emp->mobile}} </td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn btn-success edit">Update</a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

And here is the JS function where I'm using DataTables:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){

    var table = $('#tabladedatos').DataTable();

    //Edit Record
    table.on('click','.edit',function(){
      $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
      if($($tr).hasClass('child')){
        $tr = $tr.prev('.parent');
      }

      var data = table.row($tr).data();
      console.log(data);

      $('#fname').val(data[1]);
      $('#lname').val(data[2]);
      $('#address').val(data[3]);
      $('#mobile').val(data[4]);

      $('#editForm').attr('action', '/employee/'+data[0]);
      $('#editModal').modal('show');
    });


  });
</script>
```

I've seen that this error is usually caused by a mismatch between the amount of th and td, but I cannot see a mismatch in this code.
Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should delete `<tr>` tag, before and after foreach block.

```
<tbody>
  @foreach($emps as $emp)
    <tr>
      <td> {{$emp->id}} </td>
      <td> {{$emp->fname}} </td>
      <td> {{$emp->lname}} </td>
      <td> {{$emp->address}} </td>
      <td> {{$emp->mobile}} </td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn btn-success edit">Update</a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: That was the mistake! Thank you!